flask migrate don't create new models and even db.create_all() and db.drop_all() work only on 2 tables and not all the tables
i create a simple app with flask login and blueprints and then try to start and try adding new tables and relationships to the data base, it work at first and every thing were just fine but then i added a models file with 2 tables , and then all sort of thing happen , first when i do a flask db migrate it don't detact new changes and add drop tablesfor some tables that i allready dropt before.
also i try to remove every thing and restart and it's the same thing it accecept only 2 table (create with the db.create_all and drop with db.drop_all but all the others are not included and the flask db  migrate  always detect wrong changes)
you will find all code here i hope that someone can help me  thank you
 from app.extensions import db
from flask_login import UserMixin


class User(UserMixin , db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sso= db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    password= db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    service= db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = True)


    

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Users:{self.name}>'
    


this is the user model
from app.extensions import db 
from sqlalchemy import Boolean ,text




Lots_Gamme = db.Table('Rapport',
    db.Column('num_lot', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Lots.num_lot')),
    db.Column('gamme_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Gamme.id')),
    db.Column('decision_controle' , db.String()),
    db.Column('fin_de_controle' , db.DateTime , default= text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')),
    db.Column('controlé_le' , db.DateTime , default= text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')),
    db.Column('commentaire_Generale' , db.String()),
    db.Column('niveau_de_qualité' , db.Integer()),
)


class Lots(db.Model):
    num_lot = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    gamme = db.relationship('Gamme', 
                            secondary=Lots_Gamme, 
                            backref=db.backref('lot'), lazy='dynamic')
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Lots:{self.num_lot}>'



class Gamme(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer , primary_key=True)
    statut = db.Column(db.Boolean , default=True)
    date_creation = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
    date_modification = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
    modificateur = db.Column(db.String(200) , nullable = False)
    commantaire_generale = db.Column(db.String(200) , nullable = False)
    echelon_de_control = db.Column(db.String(200) , nullable = False)
    lien_plan = db.Column(db.String(200) , nullable = False)
    num_bubble_drwing  =  db.Column(db.String(200) , nullable = False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Gamme : {self.id , self.statut}>'



this is the tables that i like to add (note; it's still adding an old table that i already delete but it won't detected)
from app.extensions import db



article_fournisseur = db.Table('article_fournisseur',
    db.Column('article_reference', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('article.reference')),
    db.Column('code_fournisseur', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('fournisseur.code_fournisseur'))
)

class Fournisseur(db.Model):
    code_fournisseur = db.Column(db.Integer(200), primary_key=True)
    designation_fournisseur = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    articles = db.relationship('Article', 
                               secondary=article_fournisseur,
                               backref=db.backref('fournisseurs'), lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Fournisseur {self.code_fournisseur}>'
    

class Article(db.Model):
    reference = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    revision = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    designation_article = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Article {self.reference}>'

this is the others table that i want to add and they work yesterday,
i followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47i-jzrrIGQ&t=338s  to make relationship
i will add also the config.py an init.py files

class Config: 
    DEBUG = True
    SECRET_KEY = 'this#is#a#sicret#key'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://postgres:1234@localhost/databaseGammeDeControl'
    
    
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from app.extensions import db
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
from app import models


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    #this is to create a login session for the user 
    login_Manager = LoginManager()
    login_Manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_Manager.init_app(app)

    from app.models.user import User
    @login_Manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))


    #initilize the flask extentions Here 
    db.init_app(app)
    #With this, you can use your db object to create and interact with Flask-SQLAlchemy models in your application.
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)

    #Register Blueprints Here
    from app.main import bp as main_bp 
    app.register_blueprint(main_bp)

    from app.auth import bp as auth_bp
    app.register_blueprint(auth_bp, url_prefix="/auth")

    from app.iqc import bp as iqc_bp 
    app.register_blueprint(iqc_bp, url_prefix='/iqc')

    from app.sqe import bp as sqe_bp 
    app.register_blueprint(sqe_bp, url_prefix='/sqe')

    @app.route('/test/')
    def test_page():
        return "<h1>Testing the Flask Application Factory Pattern</h1>"
    
    return app

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db=SQLAlchemy()


i just started on flask and i try to make a profisionnal project so if any one know any other way to do things more efficent and professional , i am all ears .
thank you!!
